# How do you change a user's email address in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I've set up phabricator and added several users.  I noticed that I can change a user's real name or username, but I am unable to change their email address.  Is there some reason why this is not exposed to admins?  Is there a server setting that allows admins to change email addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be new, but they have a way now. I'll just list it here in case anyone has the same question later.

Log in to the server, where you have your Phabricator install, and use `./bin/accountadmin`. That will let you change or add accounts at will. If you just want to look at the user, you can look in the `phabricator_user` database and check the `user` table or the `user_profile` table.

Comment: Unfortunately accountadmin does not allow you to change the email of an existing user.

Comment: I did that yesterday though. I had to re-enter all account info when I changed the user, so my input when creating and changing a user was the same.

Comment: Note that while `accountadmin` does *not* let you change a user's email address (as noted above) it does let you change some of the other information related to the user (such as their password, real name, whether they are bot or an admin etc)

Answer (score 28):

You need to update the mysql database. In the phabricator_user db alter your email address in the user_email table. Administrators may not be all-powerful, but DBAs are.

Answer (score 8):

Administrators can not change email addresses because it would let them change a user's email address to their own, reset the user's password, and then log in as the user. Administrators are not all-powerful in Phabricator's permission model, and can not compromise accounts, act as other users, or violate policies.

If you need to change an address because you made a mistake when creating a new account, you can delete the account and recreate it.

Comment: We should at least be able to *view* the email addresses so we can verify if we entered the correct one, no?

Answer (score 7):

As bridiver writes, you need to change the address directly in the database. For that, you can use a helper Phabricator script to connect to the database:

```
$ phabricator/bin/storage shell
[...]

mysql> use phabricator_user;
Database changed
mysql> update user_email set address='newaddress@example.com' where address='oldaddress@example.com';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> quit
```