# Get email from username of user in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I was configuring Phabricator to work with Jabber chat. I need to find the email address of the receiver of the message. I only have the username of the receiver.

I have looked at the Conduit queries and there is a query.user method but it does not retrieve the email.

How can I get the email of the receiver from their username?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247630/how-do-you-change-a-users-email-address-in-phabricator ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phabricator does not expose email addresses, by design. We consider this information to be private.